# MongoDB: find if any field is true

Tags: mongodb

I have documents structured like this. Notice that this is ONE document, not collection:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "end_flag": false
  }
  "2": {
    "end_flag": false
  }
  ...
}
```

**Problem:** In the end, I want to count documents that have a end_flag: true in any of its fields. How can I match documents that any of X.end_flag field is true?
I have tried:

```json
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "1.end_flag": true, 
            "2.end_flag": true,
            "3.end_flag": true,
            "4.end_flag": true,
            "5.end_flag": true,
            "6.end_flag": true,
            "7.end_flag": true,
            "8.end_flag": true,
            "9.end_flag": true,
            "10.end_flag": true,
        }
    }
]
```

but I know this only works if **all** conditions are true. How can I make it **any**?
I also tried (desperately):

```json
[
    {
        "$match": {
         "$in": [ true, [
            "$1.end_flag", 
            "$2.end_flag",
            "$3.end_flag",
            "$4.end_flag",
            "$5.end_flag",
            "$6.end_flag",
            "$7.end_flag",
            "$8.end_flag",
            "$9.end_flag",
            "$10.end_flag"
            ] ] 
        }
    }
]
```

But none of them worked. I know the documents are structured poorly for this task but this is what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A- while `$or` operation is costly in mongodb, the best solutions is to **structure** your data as `array` like :

```
[
  0: {
    "number": 1
    "end_flag": false
  }
  1: {
    "number": 2
    "end_flag": true
  }
  ...
}
```

then you can **simply** query :

```
db.collection.find({"fieldName.end_flag":true});
```

this is the power of **MongoDB** 
B- if there is no way to restructure your data, then you have to use `$or` operation like this :

```
db.collection.find({
$or:[
            {"1.end_flag": true}, 
            {"2.end_flag": true},
            {"3.end_flag": true},
            {"4.end_flag": true},
            {"5.end_flag": true},
            {"6.end_flag": true},
            {"7.end_flag": true}
]
})
```

Comment: I have spend an emberassing amount of time on this... Looks like I forgot to remove $ symbol.